# отобразить ошибки в php коде

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно увидеть ошибки которые наверно генерирует php код, потому как вообще белый екран вижу. 
Спасибо.

```
    $locale_lang = $_GET['lang'];
    $locale_file = new FileReader("locale/$locale_lang/LC_MESSAGE/messages.mo");
    $local_fetch = new gettext_reader($locale_file);

    function _($text){
        global $locale_fetch;
        return $locale_fetch->translate($text);
    }
?>

<h1><?php echo _("Translate using gettext") ?></h1>

<p><?php echo _("This video shows a simple tutorial of how ot translate variables using getter.") ?></p>
```

Comment: Откройте файл лога ошибок на сервере и посмотрите в чем причина.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно всегда error_log сервера смотреть на предмет наличия в нём ошибок. 
Если linux - лог будет где то /var/log/*

```
# php  -r "phpinfo();" | grep error_log             
error_log => error_log => error_log
```

Белый экран - PHP упал. Добавляйте по одной строке в код и смотрите где падает код. Ошибка еще может быть в .err логах вашего веб-сервера.

Убедитесь, что включен вывод ошибок и что ошибки не подавляются собакой @.

Answer (score 0):

В php.ini файле есть директива display_errors - надо ее включить.

Или как вариант, добавить в скрипте PHP:

```
if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}
```